# .htaccess - Too many redirects

Tags: .htaccess

I am getting a "too many redirects" error from the following two .htaccess files.

.htaccess on domain 1

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.domain2.com/
```

.htaccess on domain 2

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /forum/ [L,R]

RedirectMatch permanent ^/$ /forum/

# Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} badsite1\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} badsite2\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Anyone know the reason for the too many redirects error?

Comment: Where are you being redirected to?  `/forum/`, maybe?  What content is in that directory?

Comment: Without the last 3 lines (ReWriteRule .* - [F]) everything redirects succesfully to /forum/ on domain 2.  But as soon as I include that code, the too many redirects error occurs.

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense.  Are you absolutely certain that that's the only thing you're modifying and not also, say, that `Options` directive?

Comment: Correct.  Right now the site is functioning, but only because the last line has been removed.  The downside is those malicious sites are able to sendi me garbage traffic this way.

Comment: Ok, then we're back to needing to figure out where the redirect is sending you.  As John's saying, let's get some `curl` output.

Answer (score 1):

Does the directory "/forum/" exist on your site in domain2?  If not, then following `RewriteCond` (Rewrite conditions) & `RewriteRule` will always result in redirecting to `/forum/`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /forum/ [L,R]
```

That would result in an infinite redirect loop resulting in a `too many redirects` error.

From your additional comments you say that the following three lines of code cause the redirect loop:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} badsite1\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} badsite2\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

By any chance is "badsite1.com" or "badsite2.com" also a part of your domain name?  For example if the literal "badsite1.com" is "fred.com" and your domain is "myfred.com" then this condition will match your site's requests.

Comment: Yes, in fact the /forum/ directory is the only active part of the site on domain2, so I'm sending all visitors there.   The weird part is, everything works fine until I add the last 3 lines (deflecting spam domain referrals).

Comment: What do you get if you perform `curl --verbose http://www.domain2.com/forum/`?  Do you get an `HTTP 200 OK` or something else?

Comment: I'm not familiar with curl and I only have a Windows laptop at my disposal.  Does curl run locally or serverside?

Comment: You can run curl from a laptop.  You can download it from http://curl.haxx.se/download.html.  Pick the Windows 32 bit generic version.  I'm also looking into what your `RedirectMatch permanent ^/$ /forum/` rule does.  That may be the culprit for the infinite redirects.

Comment: If I remember correctly there are 2 different rules regarding /forum/.  One is to redirect all traffic from domain2.com to domain2.com/forum.  The other is to redirect all 404 errors from domain1 and domain2 to /forum.

Comment: Do I need to run curl through the version of .htaccess that breaks the site?  I can't really afford it being down, even for troubleshooting purposes.

Comment: Yes, but try using your new `.htaccess` file without `RedirectMatch permanent ^/$ /forum/` and see if that resolves your problem?  Or try it later in the day during your site's low usage period.

Comment: I tried eliminating that line.  domain2.com no longer redirects to domain2.com/forum/.  404 errors are still going to domain2.com/forum/

Comment: You are correct, the `RedirectMatch permanent ^/$ /forum/` redirects `http://www.domain2.com/` to `http://www.domain2.com/forum/`.

Comment: I don't know how, but everything magically started working.  Both the RedirectMatch permanent line and the ReWriteRule .* - [F] line are now uncommented, and all URLs are working.  My host's Support previously convinced me that my .htaccess was mangled and that was the reason for the redirect issues but maybe something else was the issue.

Comment: Maybe the web server had a bad copy of .htaccess cached and was working with an older perhaps incorrect version of the file.

Comment: Just to clean up this question.  When the site allows you, you should post your own answer saying that everything just started working as expected after you replaced your .htaccess file back to the contents shown in your question.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the code was fine.  It's possible that a cached copy of perhaps incorrect code was being loaded and was causing the error.