# .htaccess mod_rewrite too many redirects

Tags: windows, apache-2.4, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Just to make things clear, this is NOT a duplicate question like [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/410086/htaccess-too-many-redirects) as core of question is different. What I'm trying to do is redirect users who try to access a site using a language code (typically `en` or `cz`) to `index.php` with language variable set. The site itself can recognise only English and Czech languages settings, every other is redirected based on visitor's IP geolocation (using an external online JSON API). But the problem is, that browser keeps redirecting on and on and it returns an error that too many redirects occurred. What's wrong? Tried to seek for an error, but couldn't see any.

This is complete `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^[a-z]{2,3}/$ /index.php?lang=$1
RewriteRule ^blog/?(.*)$ //blog.czghost.czlh/$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^ftp/?(.*)$ //ftp.czghost.czlh/$1 [R=301]
```

Also, if user writes in `index.php?lang=$1`, I need to redirect him to the nice URL variant instead. I've searched online, but it seems too complicated to me :(

I'm testing sites in my WAMP server on my Windows machine, before it's ready to deploy online.

Comment: Please give an example of the URL(s) you want to redirect from/to. There are several errors with the directives you have posted, so none of those can be working as intended.

Comment: `czghost.czlh/cz/` should rewrite to `czghost.czlh/index.php?lang=cz` (but the actual page should redirect to the `/cz/` variant). However `czghost.czlh/blog/<anything>` should redirect to `blog.czghost.czlh/<anything>` and similarily the `czghost.czlh/ftp/<anything>` should redirect to `ftp.czghost.czlh/<anything>`. Isn't it too complicated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've not actually stated the URL(s) you are requesting that trigger the redirect loop?

However, from the directives you have posted, it would seem that any request of the form `/blog<anything>` or `/ftp<anything>` would result in a redirect loop.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^blog/?(.*)$ //blog.czghost.czlh/$1 [R=301]
> RewriteRule ^ftp/?(.*)$ //ftp.czghost.czlh/$1 [R=301]
> ```

Apache mod_rewrite does not support protocol-relative URLs in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* - they are simply seen as root-relative (ie. a URL-path relative to the document root). You presumably see the result of this redirect loop in the address bar of your browser? It will go something like this:

- Initial request: `http://example.com/blog/xyz`
- Redirects to `http://example.com//blog.czghost.czlh/xyz`
- Redirects to `http://example.com//blog.czghost.czlh/.czghost.czlh/xyz`
- Redirects to `http://example.com//blog.czghost.czlh/.czghost.czlh/.czghost.czlh/xyz`
- etc.

You need to include the protocol. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/?(.*)$ https://blog.czghost.czlh/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I've also included the `L` (`last`) flag, since you want the redirect to trigger immediately, not run the risk of being further rewritten. This should really come before the internal rewrite (that rewrites to `index.php`).

You will need to make sure you have cleared the browser cache, as the erroneous 301 (*permanent*) redirect will have been cached by the browser. It can be easier to test with 302 (temporary) redirects for this reason.

Your `blog` and `ftp` rules can be handled by a single directive, using *alternation*. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(blog|ftp)/?(.*)$ https://$1.czghost.czlh/$2 [R=301,L]
```

---

> ```
> RewriteRule ^[a-z]{2,3}/$ /index.php?lang=$1
> ```

You don't have a capturing group (ie. parenthesised subpattern) in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, so the `$1` backreference will always be empty. This should be rewritten as:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2,3})/$ /index.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

Again, I've included the `L` flag, in order to prevent further rewriting. Note that this expects there to be a slash suffix on the end of the URL path. So, only URLs of the form `/blog/en/` (with a slash suffix) would be successfully rewritten (although maybe this is unrelated).

So, in summary, this should be rewritten something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(blog|ftp)/?(.*)$ https://$1.czghost.czlh/$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2,3})/$ /index.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

---

> Also, if user writes in `index.php?lang=$1`, I need to redirect him to the nice URL variant instead.

You can do this with an additional redirect *before* the above directives. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=([a-z]{2,3})$
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ /%1/? [R=301,L]
```

You need to use a `RewriteCond` directive to check the query string against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable (this can't be done in the `RewriteRule` directive). The preceding check against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable is to make sure we only process initial requests and not rewritten requests by the later directive that rewrites the URL to `/index.php?lang=xyz`. The `REDIRECT_STATUS` env var is empty on the initial request, but gets set to "200" (as in 200 OK - HTTP status) after the first successful *rewrite*.

This will match either `index.php`, or an empty URL path (eg. `/?lang=xyz`). `%1` is a backreference to the last matched *CondPattern* (as opposed to `$N` that is a backreference to the `RewriteRule` *pattern*). The `?` on the end of the `RewriteRule` *substitution* is necessary in order to remove the query string from the redirected URL (alternatively you can use the `QSD` flag on Apache 2.4+).

Again, best to test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect that won't be cached by the browser.

> *(From comments:)* The only thing that works properly, is the `/ftp/` redirect. `/blog/` redirect stays with unchanged URL in a blank page

You should make sure that there is no physical directory on the filesystem with the same name, ie. `/blog`. And that this subdirectory doesn't have an additional `.htaccess` file that could be overriding this. Also, make sure that there isn't a *file* that shares the same basename `blog`. eg. `blog.html` or `blog.php` etc. If there is then you will need to make sure that MultiViews (part of mod_negotiation) is not enabled. ie. `Options -Indexes -MultiViews`. If MultiViews is enabled then Apache will make an internal subrequest for `/blog.php` (for example) before mod_rewrite is able to rewrite the URL.

### Summary

```
Options -Indexes -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on

# Redirect direct requests for "index.php?lang=xyz" to "/xyz/"
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=([a-z]{2,3})$
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ /%1/? [R=301,L]

# Redirect "blog" or "ftp/<anything>" to subdomain
RewriteRule ^(blog|ftp)/?(.*)$ https://$1.czghost.czlh/$2 [R=301,L]

# Internally rewrite "/xyz/" to "/index.php?lang=xyz"
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2,3})/$ /index.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Now I understand. However, after updating .htaccess, clearing browser cookies, cache and everything, it still doesn't work. The only thing that works properly, is the `/ftp/` redirect. `/blog/` redirect stays with unchanged URL in a blank page and `/xyz/` rewrite still loops the internal redirect. Any idea on what could cause that?

Comment: "`/blog/` redirect stays with unchanged URL" - Is there a physical directory on the filesystem with the same name? (Is there an additional `.htaccess` file in this subdirectory?) "and `/xyz/` rewrite still loops the internal redirect." - Ah yes, sorry, I overlooked that - I've updated my answer to address the redirect loop when requesting `/xyz/`.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Will try out tomorrow, now I'm going to sleep. And no, double checked, there is no `/blog/` directory, nor additional `.htaccess` file then.

Comment: Is there a file that shares the same basename `blog`? eg. `blog.html` or `blog.php`, etc. If there is then you will need to make sure that MultiViews is disabled. ie. `Options -Indexes -MultiViews`.

Comment: Ah, `blog.php` blocked my redirect :D I prepared it as a gateway to two different blogs, but then decided to merge two blogs into one, and forgot to delete it :D