# Apache - Need to rewrite /contact/ to /contact.php

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Using `.htaccess` from my [previous question](https://serverfault.com/questions/905513/htaccess-mod-rewrite-too-many-redirects), I edited it to add a rewrite rule for rewriting `/contact/` to `/contact.php` and `/xyz/contact/` to `/contact.php?lang=xyz`. While the second one works, the first still looks for the actual directory which doesn't exist, returning `404` code. Both redirects to the nice URL variant work just like expected. Here is my `.htaccess` settings for that:

```
# No directory listing, no multi views, follow symlinks
Options -Indexes -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks

# Redirects and rewrites allowed
RewriteEngine on

# ...

# Redirect direct requests for "contact.php?lang=xyz" to "/xyz/contact/"
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=([a-z]{2,3})$
RewriteRule ^contact\.php$ /%1/contact/? [R=301,L]

# Redirect direct request for "contact.php" to "/contact/"
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^contact\.php$ /contact/? [R=301,L]

# Internally rewrite "/xyz/contact/" to "/contact.php?lang=xyz"
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2,3})/contact/?$ /contact.php?lang=$1 [L]

# ...

# Internally rewrite "/contact/" to "/contact.php"
RewriteRule ^/contact/?$ /contact.php [L]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> # Internally rewrite "/contact/" to "/contact.php"
> RewriteRule ^/contact/?$ /contact.php [L]
> ```

In per-directory `.htaccess` files you need to remove the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (as you have done on the earlier directives). So this should be written as:

```
RewriteRule ^contact/?$ /contact.php [L]
```

This matches requests for `/contact` and `/contact/`.

The slash prefix is not used on the `RewriteRule` *pattern* because in a `.htaccess` context, the *directory-prefix* (that notably ends with a slash) is first removed from the URL-path that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against. (The *directory-prefix* being the filesystem path of where the `.htaccess` file is located.)

Comment: I'm really dumb :D Thank you, overlooked the mistake :D

Comment: It's a common mistake - you're not dumb! ;) By contrast, if you were using these directives directly in the server config (ie. in a _server_ or _virtualhost_ context) then you would need the slash prefix, because when used in a server context, the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ matches against the full root-relative URL-path.